# How to filter search results based on status id (posted db-fiddle)

Tags: mysql

**Edit**: I've posted db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2Urz7fEhLtyHotNEoH8ZG/1

The query in fiddle displays results of plumbers who have already been sent a request.(Status Id: 1).

I will try to explain what the app does first. I hope it will make it easier to understand.

There are associations and there are plumbers. An association employs plumbers.
A plumber gets into our database once an association adds a plumber.

Once a plumber is added by an association, other associations can search plumbers in our database and add them(They can have their own plumbers which other associations can search and add).

When an association tries to add a plumber, the plumber gets a request. The plumber can either accept or reject this request to work in the association. Once the plumber accepts, the association has to confirm again or can also reject the request sent by it(after the plumber has accepted).

And then there is termination of plumber by association and there is plumber exiting from the association.

If a plumber is terminated he simply gets a notification.

When a plumber tries to exit an association, the association can accept or reject the exit request.

I am facing problem in displaying the plumbers list(when an association searches for plumbers to send request) based on the status of a plumber.

The possible statuses are:

1) StatusId: 4 - Plumber already belongs to the association(that's currently searching) - this should not be displayed in search.

2) StatusId: 1 - The plumber has been sent a request already- this should not be displayed in the search results either

3) StatusId: 2 - The plumber has accepted and association has not confirmed yet - this should not be displayed

4) StatusId: 3 - The plumber has rejected the request to work - this should be displayed in search again.

5) StatusId: 4 - The association has accepted after plumber accepts - Should not be displayed since plumber now works for association.

6) StatusId: 5 - The association has cancelled after plumber accepts - This should be displayed again in search

7) StatusId: 6  - The association terminates plumber - Should be displayed again to request.

8) StatusId: 7 - The plumber sends exit request from association - This should not be displayed

9) StatusId: 8 - The admin approves exit status - This should be displayed again in search

10) StatusId: 9 - The admin disapproves exit request. - This should not be displayed

Table:
[image: The Table]
**Edit**: I've posted a fiddle now with the following query. This   displays results of plumbers who have already been sent a request.(Status Id: 1).

```
select  0 as map_id,
    mp.maintenance_user_id,
    mp.map_id as mp888,
    m.user_id,
    m.user_name,
    m.customer_id,
    m.association_id,
    m.user_email,
    m.gender,
    m.contact_no,
    r.role_type_name,
    m.full_name,         
    m.work_area,
    m.city,
    m.contact_no,
    m.address_line1,
    m.address_line2,
    m.state,
    m.country,
    m.zip_code,
    mp.status_id,
    v.vendor_name

from svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp 
left join svk_apt_maintenance_users_details m on m.maintenance_user_id = mp.maintenance_user_id and m.is_active = 1
left join svk_apt_master_user_role_type r on r.role_type_id = m.user_role_type_id and r.is_active = 1 
left join svk_apt_vendors v on v.vendor_id = m.vendor_id and v.is_active = 1
left join svk_apt_associations a on a.association_id = mp.association_id and a.customer_id = mp.customer_id 
    and a.is_active = 1

LEFT JOIN svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp4 on mp4.maintenance_user_id = m.maintenance_user_id
            and m.is_active = 1


where   mp.role_type_id = 8 
    and mp.maintenance_role_id = 1

    and (case when mp.customer_id = 1 and mp.association_id = 1
              then mp.status_id in(3,5,6,8)
              AND

                    mp4.maintenance_user_id not IN(                    

                        select mp1.maintenance_user_id
                        from   svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp1
                        WHERE   mp1.customer_id <> 1
                                and mp1.association_id <> 1
                                 AND mp1.maintenance_user_id not IN
                                     (
                                        SELECT mp2.maintenance_user_id
                                        FROM   svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp2
                                        WHERE  mp2.customer_id = 1
                                               and mp2.association_id = 1
                                               and mp2.status_id NOT IN(3,5,6,8)

                                     )

                )  

         else
                false

         end)       


    and mp.is_active = 1
    and  mp4.status_id is null

GROUP BY m.maintenance_user_id



UNION ALL    

select  0 as map_id,
    mp.maintenance_user_id,
    mp.map_id as mp888,
    m.user_id,
    m.user_name,
    m.customer_id,
    m.association_id,
    m.user_email,
    m.gender,
    m.contact_no,
    r.role_type_name,
    m.full_name, 
    m.work_area,
    m.city,
    m.contact_no,
    m.address_line1,
    m.address_line2,
    m.state,
    m.country,
    m.zip_code,
    mp.status_id,
    v.vendor_name

from svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp 
left join svk_apt_maintenance_users_details m on m.maintenance_user_id = mp.maintenance_user_id and m.is_active = 1
left join svk_apt_master_user_role_type r on r.role_type_id = m.user_role_type_id and r.is_active = 1 
left join svk_apt_vendors v on v.vendor_id = m.vendor_id and v.is_active = 1
left join svk_apt_associations a on a.association_id = mp.association_id and a.customer_id = mp.customer_id 
    and a.is_active = 1



where   mp.role_type_id = 8
    and mp.maintenance_role_id = 1

    and (case when mp.customer_id <> 1 and mp.association_id <> 1
              then mp.status_id in(3,5,6,8)
              OR

                    mp.maintenance_user_id IN(                    

                        select mp1.maintenance_user_id
                        from   svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp1
                        WHERE   mp1.customer_id <> 1
                                and mp1.association_id <> 1
                                 AND mp1.maintenance_user_id not IN
                                     (
                                        SELECT mp2.maintenance_user_id
                                        FROM   svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp2
                                        WHERE  mp2.customer_id = 1
                                               and mp2.association_id = 1
                                               and mp2.status_id NOT IN(3,5,6,8)

                                     )





                )    


         else
                false






         end)       


    and mp.is_active = 1

GROUP BY m.maintenance_user_id;
```

Comment: please dont close. it took so much time to post this.

Comment: why did you make the second join a left outer join? shouldn't this be an inner join?

Comment: @pkgajulapalli this concept is mapping users to association.The above query returns the users who are mapped to same or different associations. But I want to return the users who are not added to the current association with respect to status_ids as I have specified above in the question.

In above query`svk_apt_other_users_associations_mapping mp`
I am using for users of same association. And the last one left join with same table with other associations to filter.
If I use Inner join, users are not shown in other associations but lists only within association

Comment: @Abhi Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Progman im asking this question for a colleague. he says he has to run script of entire application. is it safe to do that with https://www.db-fiddle.com ? i mean is it safe to do it and post link publicly.

Comment: @Progman i've posted db-fiddle. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2Urz7fEhLtyHotNEoH8ZG/1

Comment: @pkgajulapalli i've posted fiddle, please check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2Urz7fEhLtyHotNEoH8ZG/1